# Travelling to NZ - how are the Covid rules enforced in practice now?

Tags: covid-19, new-zealand

We're looking at visiting NZ later this year (from the UK) for a few weeks, probably touring round in a rented camper.

My understanding of the current Covid rules is that we'd need to test while we're there and report any positive test, followed by self-isolating (which can be in a camper van, apparently).

Now, that's tolerable but the devil / uncertainty is in the details of that - can anyone tell me how this is enforced in practice, who we report to, how strict they are about the self-isolating, penalties for messing something up etc.?

We're fully vaxxed and not looking to flout any rules - it's just that we'd like to know how strict this is likely to be in reality given the 20+ hours on a plane with 300 other people means there's a non-zero chance one or both of us gets it on the way there, and it would suck if the self-isolating thing meant we couldn't visit certain attractions* even with reasonable precautions since we know NZ has been VERY strict about Covid.

*= Even very open outdoor ones, obviously - if one of us had covid we wouldn't be doing indoor stuff / close to people.

Comment: IMO visiting a country with post arrival tests is extremely risky, no matter how poorly enforced, as you don’t want to be breaking the law. I’d consider going to Australia instead which is completely mask and test free now.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question. You say you're not looking to flout any rules, but also seem to be saying that you're wondering whether you can get away with knowingly visiting outdoor attractions while you have a positive case of COVID?? [The rules](https://covid19.govt.nz/isolation-and-care/if-you-have-covid-19/how-to-self-isolate/) are pretty simple: "Do not leave the house for any reason, unless it is a permitted reason" (permitted reasons are listed there, and while light exercise away from all people is permitted, visiting attractions is not). Plus, you feel, well, sick.

Comment: @JonathanReez I think there should be more of an element of understanding that there is personal risk around covid in general rather than "where to go where the laws are lax" as a suggestion - sure, the laws are laxer in Australia than in NZ, but covid is covid and you have a personal responsibility to not spread it around.  Just because some places have essentially given up does not mean that the chance or cost of succumbing to covid is less in those places.

Comment: You guys misunderstand our intentions. This is an expensive "once in a lifetime" trip, so it would suck if (for example) recording a positive test result meant we couldn't park the camper in various campsites, or get entry to park at a national park visitor centre to go for a walk - we're not trying to avoid the test, the reporting, or go and mingle with people if we test positive, we just don't want to end up under a quarantine so strict that we can't do *anything* even away from other folks.

Comment: @Moo what you write is an argument for "not travelling at all", so enjoy your place of residence! For people who *want* to travel, it is of course more attractive to go to a place which is not going to lock them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, you should take two RAT (rapid antigen tests, or lateral flow tests) tests after you arrive in NZ, one on the day you arrive and one on day 5 or 6.  RAT tests are widely available.

You should report the results of both tests to the Ministry of Health, who apparently will send you an email with all this info in anyway.

On a positive result, you should isolate, inform your accommodation, tourism company if using one, and the Ministry of Health.

https://covid19.govt.nz/international-travel/travel-to-new-zealand-by-air/testing-requirements-after-arriving-in-new-zealand/

However, you ask how this is enforced in practice, which is a slightly different question from theory.

It isnt enforced, you can report a negative RAT test result and no one will know.  Isolation is done at home or in accommodation and no one enforces it, you wont get a visit from any official etc checking up on you.

NZ was very strict about Covid rules, yes - but this was during the period when community spread was trying to be eliminated.  It largely worked for 18 months, allowing NZ to get vaccinated.

But since community spread started in August 2021, a lot of the rules are basically unenforced - theres no enforcement of mask rules for example, other than shop workers asking.  Plenty of businesses have given up on that.

While we have an average of 5000 cases daily in the official statistics, most officials believe the number is much higher as people just dont report positive RAT results.  There is no contact tracing any more, and you are no longer required to scan in or sign in when you visit places.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful picture of the situation "on the ground" which is exactly what we were after. I'll leave this open for a while before hitting "accept".